# About solution for filter angular2

Tags: filter, angular

I am studying angular 2 beta.

I need to create a filter that I can use on multi screens different, so how can i create it?

Please give me ideas for the solution or samples for this.

Thanks.

Comment: filter for what ? sorry unable to understand your question

Comment: angular1 `filter` is known as [`@Pipe`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) in Angular2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what filter are you looking for but there is a simple example on the [API Preview at angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/PipeTransform-interface.html)

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bSc2muD56EzLamgPiTvD?p=preview)

Simple example:

```
@Pipe({name: 'lowercase'})
class Lowercase {
  transform(v, args) {
    return v.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

And this can be used in templates like `{{name | lowercase}}`

Comparison with *angular 1.x*
[image]

Comment: Sorry about my question is not clear. thanks for your support, your sample is clear for me.